# Ethereum multiple transactions is one transaction

Tags: ether

i want to ask how / if its possible to create multiple transactions in one on ETH.

Let me explain details.

I have old eth address where i have some old tokens, but 0 eth. i think this address was compromised so i want to move all coins to new address.

But i want to make i all in one step. set up multiple coins outgoing transaction and send i only necessary eth for this transaction fee.

Is this possible in one step?

Thank you lot for any advices.
Or please let me know who can help me to do this.

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: Look at flashbots.tools, it seems based on the rescue from https://twitter.com/smpalladino/status/1373048978443472897. Don't share your private key online or with a person you don't trust.

Answer (score -1):

When it comes to sending funds to multiple addresses with a one-time fee, Manysend is the solution you're looking for. Manysend offers a user-friendly platform that allows you to easily send payments to multiple addresses in a single transaction, saving you time and reducing fees.

As for the wallet that supports this functionality, Manysend is compatible with various wallets, including popular options like MetaMask and Coinbase. You can simply connect your preferred wallet to the Manysend platform and enjoy the convenience of sending payments to multiple addresses with ease.

Comment: If you read the question is about recovering tokens from a compromised account. It is unrelated to sending funds to multiple addresses.